# Reading order of The Books of Magic

Tags: suggested-order, vertigo-comics, books-of-magic

In what order should one read *The Books of Magic*? I'm mostly concerned with the main series issues and its spinoffs - *The Books of Faerie* seems to have threads and at least one revelation that take place at different points in the main narrative (Titania's story, for one). I understand there's also a crossover with Constantine? What other threads of the story should be read alongside the main series?

I'm fine with an order that preserves the integrity of the story as it unfolds, even if it's not chronological or a release order.

Comment: http://www.tradereadingorder.com/dc-series/books-of-magic/ possibly helpful

Answer (score 2):

I can't vouch for the accuracy, but [this website](http://www.tradereadingorder.com/dc-series/books-of-magic/) gives the following reading order:

```
+ Sandman: Dream Country
+ Absolute Sandman 1
+ The Books of Magic
+ Absolute Sandman 3
+ Books of Magic: Bindings
+ Books of Magic: Summonings
+ Sandman: The Kindly Ones
+ Books of Magic: The Books of Faerie
+ Books of Magic: Reckonings
+ Sandman: The Wake
+ Absolute Sandman 4
+ Books of Magic: Transformations
+ Books of Magic: Girl in the Box
+ Books of Magic: The Burning Girl
+ Books of Magic: Death after Death
+ Books of Faerie: Auberon’s Tale
+ The Names of Magic
+ HellBlazer: Staring at the Wall
+ Books of Magick: Life During Wartime: Book 1
+ God Save The Queen
```

Comment: Appreciated! The first Books of Faerie is definitely in a good spot. But I think the Sandman books mentioned don't have much to do with Books of Magic, aside from being in the same continuity. I'm not sure what God Save The Queen is doing here. (Although that looks to be an interesting read.)

Comment: @neilfein - Unsure? Here's where it talks about the update, sounds like it is some random guy - http://www.tradereadingorder.com/blog/updated-the-books-of-magic-reading-order-added-covers-header/ - From the wiki, looks like a "set in the same universe" story.

Comment: Well, that's pretty cool, thanks! Definitely have to read that now.